# Error While installing gcc version 4.1.1-21_i386.deb

Tags: package-management

I want to install this version of gcc (so that i am able to work with Prex RTOS) .

I downloaded the files from there : http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.1/

and try to install it from terminal with the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i gcc-4.1-base_4.1.1-21_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i cpp-4.1_4.1.1-21_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgcc1_4.1.1-21_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssp0_4.1.1-21_i386.deb
sudo apt install binutils
sudo dpkg -i gcc-4.1_4.1.1-21_i386.deb
```

While installing the third package, I got this error :

```
dpkg: error processing archive libgcc1_4.1.1-21_i386.deb (--install):
libgcc1:i386 1:4.1.1-21 (Multi-Arch: no) is 
    not co-installable with libgcc1 which has multiple installed instances
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgcc1_4.1.1-21_i386.deb
```

I tried multiples times to clean packages using `sudo apt-get -f install` without success.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Debian GCC packages are not able to be installed alongside Ubuntu GCC packages (they are not co-installable as the error suggests) nor are they compatible with each other.